# Linker command failed error, xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I run my app on simulator and it works fine and launches.

But when I connect the iphone device and run the project I get the below error.

I don't understand what does it mean

```
     Ld /Users/anilkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Colgate_Oral_Care_Centre-  gnpyidirhzoloxbfrpksaeqeowve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ColTests.xctest/ColTests normal armv7
cd /Users/anilkumar/Desktop/Col
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/anilkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Colgate_Oral_Care_Centre-gnpyidirhzoloxbfrpksaeqeowve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/anilkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Colgate_Oral_Care_Centre-gnpyidirhzoloxbfrpksaeqeowve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/anilkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Colgate_Oral_Care_Centre-gnpyidirhzoloxbfrpksaeqeowve/Build/Intermediates/Colgate\ Oral\ Care\ Centre.build/Debug-iphoneos/ColTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ColTests.LinkFileList -dead_strip -bundle_loader /Users/anilkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Colgate_Oral_Care_Centre-gnpyidirhzoloxbfrpksaeqeowve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Col.app/Col -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -framework XCTest -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/anilkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Colgate_Oral_Care_Centre-gnpyidirhzoloxbfrpksaeqeowve/Build/Intermediates/Colgate\ Oral\ Care\ Centre.build/Debug-iphoneos/ColTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ColTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/anilkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Colgate_Oral_Care_Centre-gnpyidirhzoloxbfrpksaeqeowve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ColTests.xctest/ColTests

 ld: file not found: /Users/anilkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Colgate_Oral_Care_Centre-gnpyidirhzoloxbfrpksaeqeowve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Col.app/Col
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Show us the full linker command line (from the build log pane).

Comment: OK look into the `file not found` error.  See if that directory exists.

Comment: it doesn't exist. What is wrong?

Comment: Well it's the `-bundle_loader` linker option.  Check out the Xcode project settings I guess.

Comment: bundle loader is empty

Answer (score 0):

just remove the lib paths in build settings and remove your added libs and add them again

[image]

Comment: dont you added any libs

Comment: I did bt it is empty. Though the app is launching on emulator but not on the connected device.

Comment: remove the attached libs and add them again and clean the project once and then try

Answer (score -1):

In my case it worked by deleting the test target 
- went to project settings
- in the middle column with titles 'Project' and 'Targets' I deleted my target which was 'xyzClientTest'. (for me it was throwing error in the same target)

It ran successfully. I didn't need the test target as I was evaluating my developer's app.